# Python 2 iterate over nested json dictionary

Tags: json, python-2.7

I have a dict sourced from documents in Elasticsearch with JSON that looks like this:

```
{  
   u'hits':{  
      u'hits':[  
         {  
            u'_score':1.0,
            u'_type':u'input',
            u'_id':u'1',
            u'_source':{  
               u'message':u'I really love fake news tho.'
            },
            u'_index':u'gossip'
         }
      ],
      u'total':1,
      u'max_score':1.0
   },
   u'_shards':{  
      u'successful':1,
      u'failed':0,
      u'total':1
   },
   u'took':3,
   u'timed_out':False
}
```

There are several thousand documents and I am looking to get a list of each of the 'message' values. I have tried several approaches but cannot seem to get a functioning solution. My current attempt is:

```
messages = es.search(index="gossip", _source=['message'])
for key, value in messages.iteritems():
    print key, value
```

which results in:

```
hits{  
   u'hits':[  
      {  
         u'_score':1.0,
         u'_type':u'input',
         u'_id':u'1',
         u'_source':{  
            u'message':u'I really love fake news tho.'
         },
         u'_index':u'gossip'
      }
   ],
   u'total':1,
   u'max_score':1.0
}_shards{  
   u'successful':1,
   u'failed':0,
   u'total':1
}
```

Hoping somebody can nudge me in the right direction.

Comment: Try `messages[0].itertools()`

Comment: No luck `for key, value in messages[0].itertools():
KeyError: 0`

Comment: Presuming that your list of documents is an array called docs, could you not reference like so:    `messages_list = [doc['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['message'] for doc in docs]`

Comment: No luck `messages_list = [doc['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['message'] for doc in docs] NameError: name 'docs' is not defined` but also tried messages_list = [hit["title"] for hit in messages["hits"]["hits"]["_source"]] and got `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
es_res = {  
   u'hits':{  
      u'hits':[  
         {  
            u'_score':1.0,
            u'_type':u'input',
            u'_id':u'1',
            u'_source':{  
               u'message':u'I really love fake news tho.'
            },
            u'_index':u'gossip'
         }
      ],
      u'total':1,
      u'max_score':1.0
   },
   u'_shards':{  
      u'successful':1,
      u'failed':0,
      u'total':1
   },
   u'took':3,
   u'timed_out':False
}

print [ i['_source']['message'] for i in es_res['hits']['hits']]
```

Comment: one thing - try this first for a subset as it will have a hard time printing a large message list if the response is large

Comment: Works! Returns `[u'I really love fake news tho.']` so I guess now I just need to work on getting rid of the brackets and the `u'`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @nmacc the brackets are part of the list...its how it signifies the collection, I hope you won't treat it as a string

Comment: Ha, no I understand I'm just shipping those values off to a different part of the app now so it's all good. Thanks again!